# Access deployed contract's constructor's parameters from address

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, constructor

I'm using `ethers.js` but any answer will be okay !

I'm trying to access a contract's constructor's parameters that was used when deployed to make sure the contract has not been modified before being deployed by a user.

I'm able to get the code from the contract with `ethers.js` function `provider.getCode(_address)` but it doesn't include the parameters passed in the constructor of the contract.

Anyone know how this could be done ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source code, you can determine the parameters from the getCode. The way a contract with constructor parameters is deployed to the network is literally just concatenating the contract's bytecode with the ABI encoded parameters.

For example, see the [AirDropToken code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x334eec1482109bd802d9e72a447848de3bcc1063#code) and the [transaction that deployed it](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3eabd332092d31b32b45e4a51f92d52a1c3eca941c2f1a0289c383253deed0d9).

You will notice the data in the transaction begins with the contract byte code and has a little extra on the end:

```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```

If we decode this (using the source code, we know the constructor parameters):

```
var ethers = require('ethers');

// Types from the constructor
var types = [ 'string', 'string', 'uint8', 'bytes32', 'uint256' ];

// data is '0x' + the above lines
ethers.utils.AbiCoder.defaultCoder.decode(types, data);
/* [ 'Pi Day N00b Token',
 *   'PIE',
 *   18,
 *   '0xdc03b7993bad736ad595eb9e3ba51877ac17ecc31d2355f8f270125b9427ece7',
 *   BigNumber { _bn: <BN: 0> } ]
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access those parameters after a generic smart contract was deployed by a third party.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish and how much control you have on the smart contracts being deployed, here are a few options:

- check the values that these parameters influence, like the `totalSupply` if you're deploying ERC20 smart contracts. I'm thinking that if a parameter doesn't influence the state of the smart contract in any way, it isn't an important parameter, so you don't actually care to check it.
- if you have can influence the smart contract code that you want to watch, create a custom event, let's say `ContractDeployed`, fire it from the constructor with the parameters that you want, then check the events generated by that smart contract

Answer (score 0):

If the contract is verified on etherscan, you can now find the constructor parameters at the bottom of the #code tab under "Constructor Arguments"

[image: contract code on etherscan]